# Como por uma cor padrão no input color

Tags: html

Bom dia, eu tenho um `<input type='color' />` e ele só vem na cor preta, quero que ele venha na cor *white*.

Answer (score 1):

Basta definir o atributo `value` do seu campo:

```html
<input type='color' value='#FFFFFF' />
```

O valor que indicar no atributo será a cor exibida inicialmente.